# JAX-RPC webservice redirecting to https automatically

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-rpc

I have created a webservice using JAX-RPC. When the webservice is invoked, an LDAP authentication occurs which will be handled by WebSphere container and then it will be redirected back to the actual webserivce.

But when I see the logs, it shows a 302 error and the url is changed to https instead of http.

Please help me out in this regard.

The entry in the web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>MyService</web-resource-name>
    <description></description>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>          
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <description>Used by Medescription>
    <role-name>BasicUserRole</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is protected it might get redirected to https based on `user-data-constraint`. If you don't want to redirect set `transport-guarantee` to `NONE`.

```
...  
  <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```